# Rank of a matrix concatenated on the right and bottom with a column and row of ones?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have an $n \times n$ matrix, $A$, which is to be concatenated with a row and column of ones as such: $$B = \begin{bmatrix} & & & 1\\ & A & & ...\\ & & & 1\\1 & ... & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
In the most general case, if we know $rank(A) = k \le n$, can we say that $rank(B) = k + 1$? This is my intuition because the concatenation essentially "adds" a rank to the full matrix $B$, which should not be dependent on the structure of $A$ due to the zero in the lower right, but I can't think of how to prove it.

If this is not the case, then consider three more (increasingly specific) scenarios:

1) $rank(A) = n$

2) $A = A^T$ and (1) holds

3) $A$ diagonal and (1) holds

What can we say about each of these cases? Any hints or nudges in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: Consider $A = 0$. There must be some other restrictions.

Comment: Good point, clearly the rank of B will be 2 in this case. I am more interested in the following 3 scenarios, I just figured it would be best to ask the question in the most general sense first. I can't think of a counter example for each of those cases where B would not be full rank, but the proof of the result is still not obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

$rank(B)$ is not necessarily $k+1$.

For example,
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2\\
    2 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}
and
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2   & 1 \\
    2 & 3  & 1 \\
    1 & 1  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
both have rank 2

This just proves that condition 1 does not satisfy the result.

Condition 2): $A = A^T$ and $rank(A)=n$ together cannot guarantee the result either.

Let $$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

then we have $$rank(A) = rank(B) = 2$$

We can use the same example to disprove condition 3.

Actually this example can disprove all three conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexamples!